# How can I have imported modules access tkinter widgets and variables?

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter, python-module

I had this Cafe Management System whom I've separated the gui and functions into modules.

Here are some snippets:

**main.py**

```
from tkinter import *

import checkbox_operation
import receipt_operation


class cafemanagementsystem:

def __init__(self, cms):
    self.cms = cms
    cms.title("Cafe Management System")
    
    self.b1var = IntVar(value=1)
    self.b1v = StringVar()
    self.b1v.set("0")

    self.b1 = Checkbutton(self.bevmenu, command=self.check, text="Latte", variable=self.b1var, onvalue=1, offvalue=0).grid()
    self.b1a = Entry(self.bevmenu, bd=2, textvariable=self.b1v)
    self.b1a.grid()

    self.rcpt = Text(self.rcptmain, width=50, height=30, bd=4)
    self.rcpt.grid()

    self.btnrcpt = Button(self.rcptbtn, command=receipt_operation.receipt, text="Receipt").grid()

    self.btnrst = Button(self.rcptbtn, command=receipt_operation.reset, text="Reset").grid()

def check(self):
    checkbox_operation.check(self)

def receipt(self):
    receipt_operation.receipt(self)
```

**checkbox_operation.py**

```
def check(cafemanagementsytem_inst):
    if b1var.get() == 1:
        b1a.config(state=NORMAL)
    elif b1var.get() == 0:
        b1a.config(state=DISABLED)
        b1v.set("0")
```

**receipt_operation.py**

```
def receipt():
    rcpt.insert(END, "Offical Receipt\n")
    rcpt.insert(END, "Latte \t\t\t\t" + b1v.get() + "\n")
```

My problem is that I can't get `check()` and `receipt()` to work. Also, `def check(self) and def receipt(self)` gives the following error:

`TypeError: check()/receipt() takes 0 positional arguments but 1 was given`

Are there any solutions for this? Also, please tell me if the way I wrote the code contributed to the problem as I've been stuck in this problem for almost a week.

Comment: You can use `cafemanagementsytem_inst` to access those attributes inside `check()`.  Same logic should be applied on `receipt()`.

Answer (score 0):

You need to pass the proper variables into those other functions.  I'm wondering why you have `checkbox_operation` in a separate file, when it should be part of the class.  It's not good practice that those external functions need to have such detailed knowledge of the internal workings of the class.

```
    ...
    def check(self):
        checkbox_operation.check(self)

    def receipt(self):
        receipt_operation.receipt(self)
```

```
def check(cafe):
    if cafe.b1var.get() == 1:
        cafe.b1a.config(state=NORMAL)
    elif cafe.b1var.get() == 0:
        cafe.b1a.config(state=DISABLED)
        cafe.b1v.set("0")
```

```
def receipt(cafe):
    cafe.rcpt.insert(END, "Offical Receipt\n")
    cafe.rcpt.insert(END, "Latte \t\t\t\t" + cafe.b1v.get() + "\n")
```

Comment: I actually have a fully functioning script of this program except that it contains both the gui and logic in a single file. My problem is it is very hard to read since it is very long and that is where I decided to break it down into modules.

Comment: Unless there really are parts of your processing that are independent, it's not worth the trouble.  To ME, these functions look like they are part of the UI and should be in the UI class.  Agree that it can be a hard decision.